# How to Play video from an Arbitrary Time in Android?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to play video in arbitrary time for videoview in Android

```
            _player.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    _player.setMediaController(mc);
    _player.start();
```

Now I want set time: 10:20 to seek file and play it (10 min and 20 sec)

Answer (score 1):

see [VideoView.seekTo(int msec)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#seekTo%28int%29) method

Also note one thing from the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo%28int%29)

> The playback position can be adjusted with a call to seekTo(int).
>   Although the asynchronuous seekTo(int) call returns right way, the
>   actual seek operation may take a while to finish, especially for
>   audio/video being streamed. When the actual seek operation completes,
>   the internal player engine calls a user supplied
>   OnSeekComplete.onSeekComplete() if an OnSeekCompleteListener has been
>   registered beforehand via
>   setOnSeekCompleteListener(OnSeekCompleteListener).

Comment: I have three EditText for enter time...I want use this inoformations for seeking time

Comment: enter seek time from there then use videoview's seekto method

Comment: Please See this Image.  http://www.uploadtak.com/images/o2339_timeSeek.png      I want seek for this time when use enter it

Comment: after user enters it then convert the input time to milisecond then use seekTo method. where is the problem??  have you tried that yet??

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until the video is prepared to seek.

```
int seekTimeMs = (10 * 60 + 20) * 1000; // 10:20
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekTimeMs);
    }
});
```